# Updating a complex object in a database via WebAPI Controller, theorycrafting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, httprequest

I have a WebApi Controller for an application under development which is almost complete. There's one method remaining though and I'm not entirely sure which approach to take (decision making by testing input/output is not possible at this very moment due to various reasons unfortunately, therefore all I'm left with is theorycrafting).

Anyway, back to the point. My controller takes a complex model entity, transforms it into a DTO one, with only the values I need taken and then sends it to a smartphone client. That's working fine. My issue is though, I need to create a reverse method as well - something that returns the data gained from the DTO object that's processed client-side and uses it to update the complex entity inside a database. I'm new to both ASP.net and http requests in general.

I'm considering two options : one would be a Post method, although I'm not entirely sure if that could work. Another idea of mine would be a void that simply takes the data and returns it to the database (sounds good on paper, compiles just fine, but I can't test it at this stage as already mentioned, therefore hopefully someone with a deep understanding of the subjects will be willing to help).

(I think putting [HttpGet] above my void method should work, although I might be wrong)

Pardon me if the request isn't clear enough, English is not my native language. (The edit button's here though, so if you can't seem to understand something, let me know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be using a PUT/PATCH method; however, I am assuming that you want to update entities, not create them. Using Put/Patch would help to make your application RESTful.

REST is a very popular model for web api's

EDIT :
For reference
POST is CREATE,
GET is READ,
PUT/PATCH is UPDATE,
DELETE is DELETE

That is the making of CRUD to RESTful Web Api's in general